# Pulling Red Hat release level from /etc/redhat-relase

Tags: awk, sed, version

I need to script a way to pull the actual release level of Red Hat boxes into a variable.

I am focusing on the `/etc/redhat-release` file.
I thought it would be a simple `awk '{ print $7 }'`,  but RH8 has changed the value to the 6th word, so that simple solution is out.
(I have searched this site for similar questions, but the answers all related to a stable location for the value. In this case, we don't know which field number the OS Version will be in).

Examples:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)
```

I think that using `sed` is my best bet.

1. Find the first word starting with `6.`, `7.`, or `8.`, and grab that value (`[678]\.`). This is probably the safest.
2. Or grab the first word after `release`.

I'm wondering what the suggestions would be for a nice, simple way to do this using `sed` or `awk` or some other tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse one of the other `release` files that may be included.

I think RHEL has `/etc/os-release` which can provide the OS version in a variable by simply sourcing it:

`source /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_ID`

It includes a number of other handy OS related variables as well.

Comment: Hah, I just came across exactly that as the recommendation for RHEL 9+!

Comment: I like this even better than Stephen Kitt's awk statement above, as it gives me more variables that I may be able to use going forward.  :)   Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `lsb_release` for this:

```
$ lsb_release -rs
8.6
```

Another approach, which doesn’t require `lsb_release`, is to parse [`/etc/os-release`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) (which is the recommendation for [RHEL 9 and later](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2012924)):

```
awk -F'[="]' '/VERSION_ID/ { print $3 }' /etc/os-release
```

Comment: lsb_release is so nice and simple, but unfortunately I would have to install redhat-lsb-core  across thousands of servers so I can't leverage it.     The awk you supplied gives me exactly what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could isoate the field immediately before the last in a string by doing:

```
... awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

For example:

```
echo "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)"|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
6.10

echo "Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)"|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
8.5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat file.txt
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)
```

output

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /[0-9]/){print $i}}}' file.txt
6.10
7.9
8.6
8.5
```